# What is difference between " .subtitle {} " & " h2[class=subtitle] "?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I just started learning HTML & CSS recently, have many doubts this is one of it

Can anyone please explain if i have to give class to every h2 i have in my code to make work " h2[class=subtitle] {} " then why shouldn't i simply mention " .subtitle {} "

So, please explain me where can i use h2[class=value] format & where can i use .subtitle

```css
.subtitle {
  color: red;
}
/* or */
h2[class=subtitle] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="subtitle">About Me</h2>

<h2 class="subtitle">Services</h2>

<h2 class="subtitle">Contact Us</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.subtitle` will apply to *any* element that has a `class` attribute that contains `subtitle`, regardless of its type or other entries in the `class` attribute. For example, `.subtitle {}` will match all of the following elements:

```html
<h1 class="subtitle">Subtitle</h1>
<h2 class="red-text subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
<p class="subtitle text-center">Centered subtitle</p>
```

However, `h2[class=subtitle]` will only ever target `<h2>` elements that have a class attribute matching `subtitle`. It won't match if the classname has additional values, or if the element is not an `<h2>`, i.e.:

```html
<h2 class="subtitle"> <!-- matches -->
<h2 class="subtitle red"> <!-- won't match -->
<h1 class="subtitle"> <!-- won't match -->
```

It's worth noting about specificity, however. `h2[class=subtitle]` is more specific than just `.subtitle` so any styles contained it will override those defined inside of `.subtitle`.

As a general rule, you should avoid writing `[class=]` selectors though, since they're very specific and make it difficult to reuse your stylesheet for other elements, and mean a refactor is necessary if your markup changes.

---

The square bracket notation is actually called the "attribute selector", and can be used for selecting elements based on their attributes and values. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors). It's also worth noting that it's possible to use equality checks other than `=` inside of the attribute selector, as explained in the [Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#syntax) section of the MDN link above.

Comment: I didn't know that `h2[class=subtitle]` is different from .subtitle, thanks for the information ! I updated my answer to avoid incorrect informations

Comment: Wow, you just explained it as you are teaching to a kid, i am very enlightened with your point to point clear explanation. Thank you so much sir.

Comment: Worth adding that the correct replacement for `h2[class=subtitle]` would be `h2.subtitle`.

Comment: The specificity of an attribute selector is equal to that of a class selector; the extra specificity comes from the type selector, which is altogether irrelevant to this conversation since there's nothing stopping someone from writing h2.subtitle or [class=subtitle]. The problem with using an attribute selector lies in the non-technical definition of "specific": class selectors will always adapt to the document language's meaning of "class", whereas attribute selectors are specific to HTML and any other document language defining a "class" as the value of an element's class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`[class=subtitle]` target elements wich only have `subtitle` and class.

```css
[class="subtitle"]{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="subtitle">subtitle</div>
<div class="subtitle A">subtitle A</div>
```

If you don't need to specify that your element has only one class to apply your style, you should use `.subtitle`.

By adding `h2` before, you only target `h2` element with the `subitle` class applied, it's more specific.

`[...]` is usually used to select attribute like `type` in an input or custom `data-...`

```css
input{
  border:3px solid black;
}
[type=text]{
  background-color:red;
}
input[type=text]{
  /*more specific : priority*/
  background-color:orange;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="email">
```

You can check selectors and combinators [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) (MDN).

Answer (score 0):

`h2[class=subtitle]` is more *specific*  (google that...) and therefore overrules the less specific `.subtitle` selector (which would also apply to other tags which have that class).

Still, you would rather use `h2.subtitle {...}` than `h2[class=subtitle] {...}` to combine a class with a tag. `h2[class=subtitle] {...}` actually uses an *attribute* selector instead of the class selector.

Answer (score 0):

`.classname` can be used for any element you assign that class, whereas `h2.classname` is for the `H2` elements which only contain that class assignment.

If you just want to make changes for every `H2` element, just use

```html
h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using [] in a CSS selector matches attributes and their values.

h2[class="subtitle"] matches all h2 with an attribute whose value is exactly subtitle whereas h2.subtitle matches all h2 tags which contains a "subtitle" class.

You can take a look at CSS attribute selector on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: `h2.subtitle{}` is **not** the same as `h2[class="subtitle"]`!

Comment: @BenM I updated my answer. You are right: the right thing would be "h2.subtitle is the same as h2[class*="subtitle"]", wouldn't it ?